# Upgrade TeX Live 2019 to 2022?

Tags: texlive, texlive-2020

My system is Linux Mint Mate 20 (based ubuntu 20.04). The TeX Live was installed from the repository, the version is 2019. I'd like to upgrade to the recent version 2022. I found a new version 2022 (ISO) on tug site. [Here is](https://www.abrantes.pro.br/2020/06/15/instalacao-do-tex-live-2020/) instruction on how to install. But I'm afraid to install it. The directory installation of 2019 version is /usr/share/ but the new version use /usr/local/. I think there will be a problem and confusion in the paths and TeX will not work. There is no existing PPA for 2022  and I'm afraid to use instructions from tug site. Could somebody explain to me the right way to upgrade the TeX Live correctly?

Comment: If you decide to install the version from the TUG site, then you should first uninstall the PPA version. The paths will be different but that is not really a problem, as long as there is only one version then the terminal or any editor that you would like to use will be able to find it. However, if everything works in your current setup then you could also consider to keep using the older version. Although there are frequent improvements and bugfixes for the kernel, most documents should compile fine with an older version.

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/1228573/16395 is useful for you? I normally install a portable version under my home directory, and adding that in the PATH, you override whatever you have. My systems now have a system-wide minimal installation of TeX, to keep dependencies happy, and I use my own portable version which is always up-to-date.

Comment: @Marijn My Texlive 2019 works perfectly, but I need a new option that appeared in version 2020.

Comment: @nail of course I don't want to advise against upgrading, however for many new options there are workarounds for older versions to achieve the same results. Maybe if you specify which option you want to use it would be possible to find a way to make it work in TL2019.

Comment: @Marijn O, yes you are right. In fact, I use the package letltxmacro to make what I want and it works. In versions > 2020 there is command \NewCommandCopy included in TexLive and no need to load letltxmacro.

Comment: @Rmano Thank you, I did not know the partable version.

Comment: there is no harm in installing tl2022 from tug just put its bin directory in front of PATH and it will be used in preference to the system one. However `letltxmacro` is perfectly robust code, installing an entire tex distribution just to avoid that package seems overkill.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment. When I started to load letltmacro, I noted that the compilation became slow. Maybe this is a subjective perception. I think it is better to use 2019, it works very well. When I change the system to Linux Mint 21, the TexLive will be upgraded automatically.

Comment: @nail no, letltxmacro has no direct effect on speed and NewCommandCopy is essentially the same. So avoiding it will not help. Of course the command you redefine using either version may be slow but that is a feature of the local redefinition not of the copy command used to save the old one.

Comment: @Marijn For example, TL2019 doesn't include OpTeX, its first release was in 2000 and now, it is greatly improved.